# Using PCD Loader in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, jinja2

I'm using the following code to include PCDLoader.js in my html file.

```
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/PCDLoader.js') }}"></script>
```

However, I'm getting the following error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a PCDLoader.js:11 module

Failed to load resource: https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.1/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader2.js the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't import ES6 modules as global scripts. Consider to import similar to the official `PCDLoader` example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_pcd.

Comment: I'm new to three.js...could you please explain?

Comment: The idea is to use ES6 import statements. If you are not familiar with them, I suggest you study ES6 modules first. This is not a `three.js` thing but basic JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: Is there any direct approach to import it to my jinja 2 template?

Comment: Can you please explain how your app code is structured? If you only use global scripts, try it with the code from this source: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.116.1/examples/js/loaders/PCDLoader.js. It's the global script version of `PCDLoader` from `r116.1`.

Comment: it wortks now... thank you